# How do I find the domain and range of this piecewise defined function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

Are both conditions true when $x>3$? If so, how do I graph it?

$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&x^2-4&&:x>3\\
&2x-1&&:x\geq 3
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Comment: What conditions?

Comment: Is one of the inequalities in the definition of $f$ reversed here?

Comment: As written, that is not a function, as it is one-many.

Comment: Clearly something is wrong with your function definition; otherwise, both conditions are certainly not true (at least not well-defined) when $x>3$. For example, suppose $x=5$. Well, $5>3$, but $5^2-4=21\neq 9=(5)2-1$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the values for f(x) when x>3, both conditions are true, either x>3 and x≥3

Comment: Then, this is not a function.

Comment: Are you sure the first part of the definition isn't for $x<3$?